# How can a scaling factor determine positive semi-definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, positive-semidefinite

in time series analysis the sample autocovariance function is scaled by $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n-h}$.
More specifically the covariance matrix $\hat{\gamma}$ of a stationary series is defined
$$
\widehat{\gamma}(s, t) = \widehat{\gamma}(|s-t|) = \widehat{\gamma}(h) = n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})(x_t-\bar{x})
$$
where $h = |s-t|$.
In all textbooks and in my lectures it is simply mentioned that this instead of $\widehat{\gamma}(h) = (n-h)^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})(x_t-\bar{x})$ prevents the matrix $\hat{\gamma}$ from being not positive semidefinite.

I originally thought a scaling factor can not influence it but there even is an example over at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56238/question-about-sample-autocovariance-function/56273?noredirect=1#comment1117275_56273). Unfortunately, after playing around with it and seeing the reasoning (I agree) I still get the wrong answer.

Could someone please shed some light on how the scaling factor influences positive definiteness and in some way (see example) even invertibility?

Many thanks in advance, it isn't important for my course but it I can't concentrate on other things until I understood this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a scaling factor, as $h$ is different for different matrix entries. You’re right that a single positive scaling factor applied to all matrix elements can’t affect positive (semi-)definiteness.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are correct, I was sloppy in my description. We change it to a single scaling factor though. $\frac{1}{n}$ and I am trying to come to grasp how this helps?

Comment: @oliver: How do you mean "how this helps"? It's not surprising that positive (semi-)definiteness can change if you multiply different entries by different factors – that's the same as just defining a completely new matrix. If you want to know why this particular matrix is positive semidefinite and the other one isn't, that's quite a different question that has nothing to do with scaling factors.

Comment: Thank you for your patience Joriki. I am not always the best with words.
I was wondering why in particular the $\frac{1}{n}$ ensures this, or would it also be positive semi definite if we replace $\frac{1}{n}$ with $\frac{1}{m}$ for any $m > 0$ ?

Comment: @oliver: As you correctly assumed and I confirmed in my answer, an overall positive scaling factor that's the same for all entries can't change the positive (semi-)definiteness of the matrix. So if it's positive semidefinite with $n$, then it's also positive semidefinite with $m$ (since you've scaled it by $m/n\gt0$). The only reason you can't draw the same conclusion if you replace $n$ by $n-h$ is that $h$ is different for different matrix entries.